# Visualize the traces written after or before a page cyclelife in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, debugging, system.diagnostics

About asp.net application.

Can i visualize the traces that was written after or before a page cyclelife?

Like in Application_End event in Global class.

Comment: I discovered that the code: Trace.Write("test"); in Application_Start is ignored when it runs.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ASP.NET traceviewer.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wwh16c6c.aspx

Comment: OK, but with this traceviewer i can see only traces that was written in Page Context, during the application_end for example i can't see it.